# MQ Websphere - Transferring files

Tags: ibm-mq, cobol, mq

Hopefully someone can help with this as I can't seem to find the answer elsewhere.

I'm writing a COBOL routine to `PUT` and `GET` messages to an MQ queue.

The messages in question are all contained in a single file and I would like to know if the syntax of `MQPUT` can be used to just `PUT` the file or do I have to read the file and do a `PUT` of each individual message?

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp any good to you? If not, it would be nice to know which OS you are using.

Comment: You have to go record at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of MQPUT API says that the message to be put is passed as buffer. The application must fill the buffer with data to be put. So you can either read the entire file to a sufficiently sized buffer and send it or read one record at a time from the file and send it. It depends on how your receiving application wants the message format to be. Can it process the whole file as one message or one record at a time.

Comment: Thanks for that and it appears to be as I suspected. I was hoping I could just use some sort of command to PUT the 'filename.txt' without me having to actually read the file but it appears i'm not going to be able to do that. Looks like i'll have to read the records and if i'm doing that I may as well send them as individual messages rather than put them all in the buffer and send it as one message. Now need to find out what the maximum length of the MQ buffer is to see if I can fit an entire file in one message!

Comment: @AndyBSG I would caution against dumping a multi-record (multi-transaction) file into a single message. In many processing systems 1 record = 1 transaction. Dumping many transasactions into a single "package" leads to inter-transactional dependecies that can be difficult to deal with. The only time I would consider dumping a whole file into a message is where the file represented a single processable item such as an XML document. Outside of that, just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.